# Angular resize directive -- not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I modified the code found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.directive('resize', function ($window) {
  return {
    //restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var w = angular.element($window);

      alert('Rezise');

      w.bind('resize', function() {
        scope.$apply();  
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This does not work when the browser  windows is resized only refreshed...what am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean run? If you mean alert function in directive link, this will only run one time. If you want to trigger this after window resize, you can put alert into bind like: w.bind('resize',function(){alert('resize!'); scope.$apply(); });

Comment: oh...so any resizing i do i need to repearlt in each handler

Comment: what do you mean repearIt? @Alex.Barylski

Comment: typing on phone...typo...repeat i meant

Comment: Yeah, I think so. And I suggest you not to use watch to change the style. You'd better put this code into resize callback function. And why don't you use css to handle responsive interface?